# Installing a pip package from a local SVN checkout

Tags: python, svn, package, pip

I have a clone of another python project (that has a setup.py etc.) in my svn repository. I want to install tell pip to install from this directory. However it's an internal svn repo and is accessible via the `svn://` scheme, not `http://`.

I can checkout the directory fine like so `svn co svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version ./foobar`, then install it with pip: `pip install foobar/`, however I can't make it do it all in one go.

Here is what I've tried and the output:

```
pip install svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version
...
  File ".../virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.5.egg/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 110, in get_url_rev
    url = self.url.split('+', 1)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and

```
pip install svn+svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version
...
File "...virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.5.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2424, in scan_list
raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'svn+svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version', 'at', '+svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version')
```

Both of these problems happen with or without `#egg=packagename` at the end of the URL (with the same error message).

and as an editable URL:

```
pip install -e svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version#egg=package
Obtaining package from svn+svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version#egg=package
  Checking out svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version#egg=package to ../virtualenv/src/package
svn: URL 'svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version#egg=package' is not properly URI-encoded
```

So SVN complains if there's a `#egg=package` at the end of the url, and if i leave it out, I get this error:

```
pip install -e svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version
--editable=svn://172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/package/our-version is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package
```

How do I install a package from an SVN link with pip?

Comment: Did you mean `svn+ssh` rather than `svn+svn` by chance?

Comment: Did you try: pip install svn+svn://fuulpath/repo#egg=packagename ? Try it please.. and if it does not work, report it in the issue tracker.

Comment: @Hugo, yes I tried svn+svn://…#egg=packagename, same "Expected version spec in" error

Comment: @Marc, svn+ssh:// didn't work, got an error of "svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://rmccann@172.31.1.3/Development/Common/ThirdParty/Python/packagename/our-version'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an open bug right now. Paul Nasrat is taking a look at it and opened and issue.

Follow the https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/252

Comment: Just for the record, this bug has been fixed in the latest versions of pip. I love Open Source!